# Matlab mexFunction(): when and how many times is it called?

Tags: matlab, mex

A question about Matlab and C function (I'm not expert in Matlab):

I have a working matlab code (downloaded from internet) which calls 
a function 'foo':

```
[output] = foo(input)
```

Now, this function 'foo' is defined inside a 'C' file (foo.c), which was then compiled as a library for Matlab (foo.mexa64).
Looking at foo.c, I can see  there are two functions:

1. `void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])`
2. `void foo(double* out, double* in);`

As I understand, the `mexFunction()` allocates pointers for input and outputs, and fill them with proper data from Matlab code.

My question is: if Matlab calls `foo` several times, is `mexFunction()` called everytime or it is called just the first time?

Comment: The `foo` function is called from `mexFunction` (in the C file). `mexFunction` acts like a gateway and is called each time you call `foo` in Matlab (it's like the entry function). However, this call does not impact your performance that much.

Answer (score 2):

It is called every time `foo` is called; the inputs of the MEX function are in general different, therefore, the desired outputs need to be re-computed by the MEX function.

Answer (score 1):

`mexFunction` is called very time the MATLAB-`foo` is called.

That's just how the mex-interface works:

You give MATLAB a mex-file and MATLAB just calls the `mexFunction` out of this library, everytime you invoke the function.
Basically, MATLAB doesn't care about anything else in your library.

If you'd like to call only the C-version of `foo`, you might want to look into the documentation of `loadlibrary` and the referenced function therein.

Comment: using `loadlibrary` on the C-version of `foo` would only work if the shared library *exports* that function. By default MEX-files only expose the `mexFunction` gateway rountine, unless you manually compile it to export other symbols as well.